# Page Not Found in title of WordPress page on template_redirect using include()

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I've added a custom rewrite rule to my Wordpress site like so:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'register/bronze', 'index.php?action=register&type=2', 'top' );
```

Then within the `template_redirect` action, I check against the `action` querystring variable and load my include like so:

```
$action = get_query_var( 'action' );

if( $action == "register" ) {
    include( BG_FILE_PATH . '/templates/register-brand.php' );
    exit;
}
```

This all works fine and my custom template is displayed, however, the page title appears as "Page not found | Site Name".

Is there a way I can set the page title from my custom template? I'm trying to avoid setting these pages up as a Wordpress Page since they're fundamental to the running of the site, I don't want one of the admins to change the page settings or delete the page entirely.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

WordPress is likely overwriting your title because its still throwing a 404 (you can verify this using firebug).

WordPress will typically throw 404s when including files in the template redirect.

You need to reset the header using code like this :

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->is_404 = false;
status_header( '200' ); //if status_header doesn't work, try header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")

//now that you reset the 404, you can proceed with your include
$action = get_query_var( 'action' );

    if( $action == "register" ) {
        include( BG_FILE_PATH . '/templates/register-brand.php' );
        exit;
    }
```

This should reset the status header and allow the title of your included file to appear normally. No need for javascript :)

Comment: @Scrooby did you have a chance to try my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by inserting a small piece of JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.title = 'your title here';
});
</script>
```

If you want the title to be dynamic then replace with:

`document.title = <?php echo 'your dynamic title here'; ?>;`